# no-www CNAME in windows DNS

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, cname-record

I've asked the sysadmin of a client of mine (runs windows) to create the following CNAME records for their new website:

```
www.example.com CNAME foobar-web-server.com
example.com     CNAME foobar-web-server.com
```

The problem is that he cannot create the second entry.
I know how this is possible in Linux with bind, by using an ending dot on the alias, but how is it possible in windows DNS?

I guess what he sees looks like:
[image]
<sub>(source: [iisanswers.com](http://www.iisanswers.com/dns_for_iis_files/image013.jpg))</sub>

He tells me that leaving the "Alias name" blank gives him an error.

Any ideas?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say what the error is, but it is probably correct. The root of the domain will have at least SOA and NS records (and possibly MX and A records too). DNS doesn't allow a CNAME to coexist with other records. See [RFC 1034 section 3.6.2](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1034.html#sec-3.6.2):

> If a CNAME RR is present at a node, no
>   other data should be present; this
>   ensures that the data for a canonical
>   name and its aliases cannot be
>   different.

[RFC 1912 section 2.4](http://www.apps.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1912.html#sec-2.4) has some further examples:

> A CNAME record is not allowed to
>   coexist with any other data. In other
>   words, if suzy.podunk.xx is an alias
>   for sue.podunk.xx, you can't also have
>   an MX record for suzy.podunk.edu, or
>   an A record, or even a TXT record.

You will have to use an A record for example.com instead of the CNAME.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll accept it. I cannot validate it though because the sysadmins of the client don't know how to do this and are afraid to set up another A record for this. Doh.